# reading in files in python and powershell

Tags: python, powershell, hash, sha1

I'm in the process of moving a bunch scripts from PowerShell to Python for more cross platform compatibility.  But I'm having issues with reading in files and getting the same hash.  In PowerShell the function I'm using is:

```
Function Get-Hash {
param (
    [string]$someText
)
$hasher = new-object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = new-object -TypeName System.Text.UTF8Encoding
return ([System.BitConverter]::ToString($hasher.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($someText)))).Replace("-","")
}
```

In Python I'm doing this:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.sha1(some_text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
```

Using these two functions I can get the same hash for a string.  For example, the hashes match when doing this:

```
#Powershell:
get-hash -someText 'testing'
#Python:
hashlib.sha1('testing'.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
```

However the issue arises when I try to read in a file with a line break in it:

```
#Powershell:
$fileContent = get-content 'c:\path\to\file.txt'
get-hash -someText $fileContent

#Python:
with open('c:\path\to\file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file: 
    file_content = file.read()
hashlib.sha1(file_content.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest().upper()
```

The hashes do not come out the same.  I'm thinking it's the way I'm reading in the files, but I can't seem to get them to match up.

Comment: Why are you encoding a file before hashing it? Read it as binary data and hash the raw binary data.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I get an error in Python 'Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing' `hashlib.sha1(file_content).hexdigest().upper()`

Comment: `hashlib.sha1(open('c:\\path\\to\\file.txt','rb').read()).hexdigest().upper()`

Comment: But you still may not get the same value because you are hashing an encoded string containing the file data in PowerShell whereas here you are hashing the file's *binary* contents, which is the recommended way to hash a file

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to strip? Like `file_content.strip()` ?
Or try to remove newlines: `''.join((c for c in file_content if c != '\n'))`

Comment: .strip() gives me the same hash as without .strip()
the removing newlines gives me a different hash, but not the same as the Powershell function.